# Knockoutjs ; custom component with inner markup refering to caller $data and its $parent

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create a custom component having some inner markup that should refer to the caller bindingContext, because the inner markup refers to caller $data and $parent, 
for $data there is no problem due to the data option on template binding, but what about its $parent ?

I found a crappy solution changing ko.bindingContext.prototype['createChildContext'] function 
setting self["$parent"] in this way :

`self['$parent'] = parentContext['$parent'] === self["$data"] ? parentContext['$parents'][1]:parentContext['$data'];`

no idea how to handle self['$parents'] :/
what do you think about it ?
is there a clean way to do it ?

thank's in advance
kolja
**jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/koljagava/nyh565xp

Comment: In your model that's exposed as $data, can you add a reference to its $parent? Then you'd do something like $data.parent.someObservable ...

Comment: Yes ,in some tricky way it is possible.I'm looking for a clean implementation. If  it is possible

Comment: I've used that technique a lot in knockout viewmodels -- but I haven't used components yet, so I don't know offhand how you'd change your design to pass in a reference to the parent when initializing your child component's model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `$parentContext` ([discussed here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)).

The node within the child template becomes

```
<div data-bind="text:variable1 + ' ' + $parentContext.$parents[1].someVariable()">
```

```js
ko.components.register("parent-component", {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.someVariable = params.variable;
    this.innerContext = {
      variable1: "variable1",
      logIt: (f) => {
        console.log(f);
      }
    }
  },
  template: "<!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->"
});

ko.components.register("child-component", {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.params = params;
  },
  template: "<!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes, data:$parent} --><!-- /ko -->"
});

ko.applyBindings({
  someVariable: ko.observable('someVariableWhoseValueIsHere')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<parent-component params="variable: someVariable">
  <div data-bind="with:innerContext">
    <child-component>
      <div data-bind="text:variable1 + ' ' + $parentContext.$parents[1].someVariable()">
    </child-component>
    </div>
</parent-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : using ko [customBinding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html)

```js
    ko.bindingHandlers.withCorrectBinding = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var idx = bindingContext.$parents.indexOf(valueAccessor());
            //if databinding is not in parents lets ko do normal binding 
            if (idx === -1)
              return;

            var childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(
                valueAccessor);
            childBindingContext.$parent = null;
            childBindingContext.$parents = [];
            if (idx+1<bindingContext.$parents.length){
              //$parent
              childBindingContext.$parent = bindingContext.$parents[idx+1];
              //$parents
              childBindingContext.$parents = bindingContext.$parents.splice(0,idx);
              //$rawData ???
              //$parentContext ???
            }

            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, element);

            // Also tell KO *not* to bind the descendants itself, otherwise they will be bound twice
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings({
     var1: "var1Value",
      innerContext:{
         var2 : "var2Value",
            innerInnerContext : {
             var3 : "var2Value"
            }
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with:innerContext">
  <div data-bind="with:innerInnerContext">
    <hr/>
    <div data-bind="with:$parent">
      Does not work<br>
      var2 : <div data-bind="text:var2"></div>
      var1 : <div data-bind="text:$parent.var1||'not found!'"></div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div data-bind="withCorrectBinding:$parent">
      It works!<br>
      var2 : <div data-bind="text:var2"></div>
      var1 : <div data-bind="text:$parent.var1"||'not found!'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```